# Creating new verbs with -um and nouns

Tags: verbs, affixes

Some of my friends connect -umi to nouns like in the examples below. In brackets are the meanings I caught through context.

- varsoviumi (talk about Varsovio, look at pictures of the city and/or walk around in it)
- telegramumi (chat or hang out using the messaging service Telegram)
- matematikumi (do maths as a hobby, have fun with maths)

I want to know if this use of -um is grammatically correct, or considered *playing with words* / *creative  language*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certe oni povas fari vortludojn per la sufikso *-um.* Unu el la plej konataj estas *geumi*, kiu povas havi diversajn signifojn depende de la kunteksto: amindumi, flirti, seksumi kun aliseksa partnero.

Tamen, se oni kreas tiajn vortludojn, oni atentu, ĉu ĉiu komprenos ilin. Ĉe *varsoviumi* mi tuj pensis pri vizito al Varsovio kun ĝiaj interesaĵoj, butikoj, restoracioj ktp, eĉ ekster iu ajn konteksto.

Sed la vorton *telegramumi* verŝajne komprenas nur tiuj, kiuj uzas tiun servon kaj parolante kun aliaj, kiuj uzas la saman servon.

*Matematikumi* laŭ mi estas tute bona vorto tuj komprenebla, i.a. pro tio, ke la unua signifo de *-umi* estas *agi iamaniere per la radiko de la vorto*. Do oni iel agas per matematiko. Tamen ĝi laŭ mi ne nepre aludas nur al hobio. Mi kredas, ke amiko de profesoro pri matematiko povus diri al li: „Ĉu vi matematikumas eĉ dum via libertempo?”.